# jQuery click handler only works once

Tags: jquery

I have started to learn jQuery and am going through some very simple examples but have run into problems already. I am changing the body upon the click of a day button and again a different background for a night button.

What I am finding is that the click handler is only working once an if I click the night button first then the day button won't work? Can anyone advise or share a best practice with this?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
 <body>

  <h1>My Website</h1>

  <button id="first">Day</button>
  <button id="second">Night</button>



  <script>
  $(function() {
    $('button#first').click(function() {

      $('body').addClass('day');
    });
    debud

    $('button#second').click(function() {

      $('body').addClass('night');
    });

  });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Runnable copy at http://jsbin.com/ufadul/3/edit

Comment: You need to make friends with the JavaScript debugger in the browser. If you suspect the click handler isn't working on subsequent clicks, as you did, don't assume, set a breakpoint in the click handler and click the button. You'd have noticed immediately that the handler runs, and that the class is added to the body. If you had then used the DOM inspector in the browser, you'd have seen the problem immediately. [So go install Chrome and press F12 without further ado!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLqswS6r-e0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This script will continue adding these classes to your body tag instead of replacing them. `.night` is taking priority over `.day` because of the position in the CSS.

Use the following to prevent this from happening:

```
$(function() {
    $('button#first').click(function() {
      $('body').removeClass('night');
      $('body').addClass('day');
    });

    $('button#second').click(function() {
      $('body').removeClass('day');
      $('body').addClass('night');
    });

  });
```

Comment: Darkness will prevail! Oh, just CSS ordering. Right.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the class also this should sort out your issue

```
$(function() {
    $('button#first').click(function() {
      $('body').addClass('day');
      $('body').removeClass('night');
    });

    $('button#second').click(function() {
      $('body').addClass('night');
   $('body').removeClass('day');
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('button#first').click(function() {
      $('body').attr('class','day');
    });

    $('button#second').click(function() {
      $('body').attr('class','night');
    });

});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/z6knm/)